# Replace one character with multiple characters

Tags: c, string, char, c-strings

I need to replace `" "` (space) with `", "` (comma and space).
I have function which receive string as char* and after replacing all this characters prints string on screen.

```
char* PrintComma(char* Text) {
  for (int i = 0; i < strlen(Text); i++) {
    if (Text[i] == ' ') {
        Text[i] = ',';
    }
  }
  return Text;
}
```

This replaces `" "` with `","` but I need `", "`. I'm not allowed to use a second string or array for saving temp data. I can use only this one string.

Example:

```
Input => "Hello world my name is"
Output => "Hello, world, my, name, is"
```

Comment: Step 1: count the spaces. Is that enough of a hit, or do you need more?

Comment: Step 2: work backwards from the end of the string.  Note: buffer pointed to by `Text` must be large enough to hold the longer result string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem seems like a perfect setup for [`memmove()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memmove.3.html) which is a library function that copies bytes between two strings but handles overlapping memory blocks.

```
memmove(
    char_pointer + make_room_at + room_to_make,
    char_pointer + make_room_at,
    init_size - make_room_at + room_to_make
);
```

Here is the application using `memmove()`.

```
char* PrintComma(char* Text) {
  for (int i = 0; i < strlen(Text); i++) {
    if (Text[i] == ' ') {
      memmove(
          Text + i + 1,
          Text + i,
          strlen(Text) - i + 1
      );
      Text[i++] = ',';
    }
  }
  return Text;
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that this requires the space for the commas to already be present. This is sort of counter-intuitive, as it requires allocating the space needed.

Comment: `memmove` is not "optimized for string with overlap", it's the only function in the standard library that's guaranteed to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example. The input buffer must be large enough to store the replaced string, as the requirements state that no new string should be created.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void PrintComma(char* Text)
{
  char* str = Text;
  size_t c, len = strlen(Text);
  for (c = 0; Text[c]; Text[c] == ' ' ? c++ : *Text++);

  for (size_t i = 0; i < len + c; i++)
  {
    if (str[i] == ' ')
    {
        str[i] = ',';
        char last = ' ';
        for(size_t u = i + 1; u < len + c; u++)
        {
            char current = str[u];
            str[u] = last;
            last = current;
        }

        i += 2;
    }
  }
}

int main(void)
{
  char tmp[100] = { 0 };
  const char* TEST = "Hello world my name is";
  memcpy(tmp, TEST, strlen(TEST));

  printf("Input: %s\n", tmp);
  PrintComma(tmp);
  printf("Output: %s\n", tmp);

  return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
Input: Hello world my name is
Output: Hello, world, my, name, is
```

Comment: Sorry, it was a mistake. I do wonder why you copied the strings manually instead of using a library function like the other answer, though.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirements:

> I have function which receive string as `char*` and after replacing all this characters prints string on screen.

I don't think you're looking to replace a space with a comma-space. Instead, I think you want to go through the string and print all the characters. When you encounter a space, you print an extra comma. Here's roughly how to do that:

```
void PrintComma(char *text)
{
    const size_t len = strlen(text); // don't call on every iteration

    for(size_t i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if(text[i] == ' ')
            putchar(',');

        putchar(text[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two requirements:
1) The spaces **must** be replaced.
2) You cannot use another char array.

These lead to the assumption that the input char* must have adequate allocated space for all the new `,`s.

In that case, this would work.

```
char *PrintComma(char *Text) {
  int numberOfSpaces = 0, orignalLength = strlen(Text);
  for (int i = 0; i < strlen(Text); i++) {
    if (Text[i] == ' ')
      numberOfSpaces++;
  }
  for (int i = orignalLength - 1, j = orignalLength + numberOfSpaces - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    Text[j] = Text[i];
    j--;
    if (Text[i] == ' ') {
      Text[j] = ',';
      j--;
    }
  }
  return Text;
}
```